# WSS V3 - 403 Error in folder of document library in extended webzone

Tags: wss-3.0, forms-authentication, document

I've got a server with wss v3 and i'm using a fba with sql-membershipprovider. The users which are using fba come to an extended webapplication. From outside this user must pass our ISA server where SSL-termination is active.

Everytime someone uses a folder in a document library on this site a user from the fba-zone gets an 403-error when he hits the document library.

Can you help me?
Steffen

Answer (score 1):

Are there any specific permissions applied to this folder item that aren't apparent in the List itself?

Comment: Nope, it's nothing else but standard